# Get row count in multiple join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

i have 4 tables

1) comp_login

```
id          com_name                            co_logo           
------  ----------------------------------  ------------------
 1  UNFAN                               default_logo.png  
 2  T&P                                 default_logo.png  
 3  Elliot                              default_logo.png  
 117  walkin                              default_logo.png  
118  12 starShipping Management          default_logo.png  
119  ABS Marine                          default_logo.png  
120  Accord Marine Management            default_logo.png  
121  Admiral Marine                      default_logo.png  
122  AET                                 default_logo.png  
123  Air Borne Rec.Pvt.Ltd.              default_logo.png  
125  Apex Marine                         default_logo.png
```

2)m_medicine

```
 Med_Id  G_Name                                B_Name                                                      
------  -------------------------------  ---------------------
   1  Acetylsalicylic acid                  Aspirin, aspro                                                     
   2  Aciclovir                             Zovirax, acyclovir                                                 
   3  Amoxicillin + clavulanate             Augmentin, co-amoxcylav                                            
   4  Artemether + Lumifantrine             Riamet                                                             
   5  Azithromycin                          Zithromax                                                          
   6  Cetirizine                            Zyrtec                                                             
   7  Ciprofloxacin                         Ciproxin , Cipro                                                   
   8  Dizepam                               Valium                                                             
   9  Docusate with senna (for equivalent)  Coloxi                                                             
  10  Doxycyline                            Neo-Dagracyline, Unodox,
```

3)m_shipinv

```
    Id   MedId  ShipId  
------  ------  --------
 1       1      2918
 4       2      2918
 5       3      2918
 6       4      2918
 7       5      2918
 9       6      2918
10       7      2918
11       8      3095
```

4)tbl_vesselmaster

```
    id   co_id  vessel_name                
------  ------  ---------------------------
 2918     123  Sima Sadaf   
 2930     123  Aegean Odyassey            
 2925     123  Apj Jad                    
 2923     123  Astor                      
 2924     123  Astro                      
 2941     123  Discovery                  
 2937     123  Disney  Fantasy            
 2919     123  Disney Cruise              
 2940     123  Disney Dream               
 2933     123  Disney Magic               
 2934     123  Disney Wonder 
 3095     125  sdare
```

i want it to display only the vessels that are owned by the company ... I want to only display Sima sadaf... Because one company has many vessels and sima sadaf is vessel of company_id 123. So only the vessels that company owns should be displayed. The vessel sdare should not be displayed as it is not the part of the company

```
Vessel_ID   Vessel_Name   Total_Medicine
----------   ----------   ----------------
 2918         Sima Sadaf        7
```

Comment: I cannot see `vessel_id`m and `id` in `m_shipinv` appears to be redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT vs.id as Vessel_ID, vs.vessel_name, COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) Total_Medicine
FROM t_vesselmaster vs
INNER JOIN m_shipinv m ON vs.id = m.ShipId
INNER JOIN comp_login cl ON vs.co_id = cl.id
WHERE vs.co_id = 123
GROUP BY vs.vessel_id, vs.vessel_name;
```

Comment: but it is displaying me both Sima Sadaf and Sdare ... I want to only display Sima sadaf... Because one company has many vessels and sima sadaf is vessel of company_id 123. So only the vessels that company owns should be displayed @saharshShah

Comment: ?? can you please help

Answer (score 1):

Below should get you started. I did not see the relevance of the medicine name in the query. I am also assuming that the comp_login id corresponds to the vessel id. I am not sure how else it would relate in the schema. Below a good starting point for the query.

```
SELECT
    vs.vessel_id,
    vs.vessel_name,
    COUNT(m.id)
FROM
    `t_vesselmaster` vs
    INNER JOIN `m_shipinv` m
        ON vs.id = m.ShipId
    INNER JOIN `comp_login` cl
        ON vs.id = cl.id
GROUP BY vs.vessel_id, vs.vessel_name
```